# CSS style for radios in Tapestry 5

Tags: java, css, radio-button, tapestry

How can I get rid of the box look of radio buttons in IE8? They look like this: [image: radios in IE8]

They look normal in other browsers. I'm using Tapestry 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a border around all `INPUT` tags which most likely comes from your own css somewhere as I don't believe tapestry adds it by default.

Adding this  to your css should resolve it.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

If it doesn't, you'll have to share your html and your css so we can have a closer look.